# Relation between chief and compositions series of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Is there an example of a group with a composition series (of finite length) but without a chief series (of finite length)?

Is there an example of a group with a chief series (of finite length) but without a composition series (of finite length)?

[Definition of composition series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series)

[Definition of chief series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_series)

Comment: Isn't then the principal series of any group $G$ just $\{1\}, G$? Both the terms are normal in $G$ and it is definitely a minimal one...

Comment: I misnamed it! :) I meant a chief series.

Comment: A normal series is also subnormal, so every chief series can be refined into a composition series.  This means any group with a finite composition series also has a finite chief series.

Comment: Not sure about the other direction though.

Comment: @W4cc0: You have it backwards.  I said a chief series can be refined to a composition series, you're objecting that a composition series may not be able to be refined to a chief series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G$ be the semidirect product ${\mathbb Q}^2 \rtimes {\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb Q})$ with the natural action. Then $G$ has a chief series $1 < {\mathbb Q}^2 < {\mathbb Q}^2 \rtimes \{\pm I_2\} < G$ and, since the action on ${\mathbb Q}^2$ is irreducible and ${\rm PSL}(2,{\mathbb Q})$ is simple, these are the only normal subgroups of $G$. Since ${\mathbb Q}^2$ has no finite composition series, neither does $G$.

It would guess that having a finite composition series implies having a finite chief series.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $G$ has a composition series. If you take any series (proper inclusions)

$$1 < N_1 < \cdots < N_t < N_{t+1} = G$$

with each $N_i$ normal in $G$, by Jordan-Hölder the length of this series is at most the composition length of $G$. Hence we can find a minimal normal subgroup $N \neq 1$ of $G$. Then we find a chief series of $G$ by considering $G/N$ and applying induction on the composition length of $G$.